# Access session variable in View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Since I can't access a session variable in the View, I wonder if I need do add something more to the view to get it to work?

Inside my View:

```
@Session[ComputerNumber].ToString()
```

Controller:

```
Session["ComputerNumber"] = game.RandomNumber();
```

The error message:

> *Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 'ComputerNumber' does not exist in the current context*

Comment: @Soner Gönül How do you get the yellow background?

Comment: You can use "Blokequote" for that. See: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#simple-blockquotes

Comment: OK, Thanks! I will use that next time!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use `Session` in the view, you just need to use string indexer, just like in your controller. In your case `ComputerNumber` is not a string, it is a variable which does not exist. Change

```
@Session[ComputerNumber].ToString()
```

to

```
@Session["ComputerNumber"].ToString()
```

and it should all be working