# how to access session data from layout c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Good day,

I am trying to pass a user last name into my layout.

In my home index I get my user last name and assign it to my session.

```
var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        var usuerInDb = _user.GetUsuario(userId);
        HttpContext.Session["LastName"] = usuerInDb .LastName;
//More code here ....
return view();
```

What I would like to do is to acess "LastName" from my session and assign it to my layout in some way like the following

```
//Layout
//....more code
Hello @session["LastName"]
```

How should I do it? I also accept other approaches.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried exactly what you have, but with a capital S? `@Session["LastName"]`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access session variable in View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34380363/access-session-variable-in-view)

Comment: I'm not absolutely sure what you are asking, but couldn't you do `var last_name = usuerInDb.LastName;` then use it for not only `HttpContext.Session["LastName"]` but other places?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using User Claims, to avoid bloating the session with a lot of user information.

https://korzh.com/blogs/net-tricks/aspnet-identity-store-user-data-in-claims

Answer (score 1):

if are usin MVC you can use TempData["LastName"]
replace 
HttpContext.Session["LastName"] = usuerInDb .LastName;
to 
TempData["LastName"] = = usuerInDb .LastName;

In view..
Hello TempData["LastName"]