# Why doesn't this variable get the correct value?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, boolean, session-variables

I'm trying to pass booleans between a controller and view, but in one particular case it's not working and I can't see what I'm doing wrong.

In the controller, I declare a variable, use an expression to give it a value, 
and assign that value to a Session object. In the view, I retrieve the value from the session and store it in a new bool. I've also created some some other booleans in the way in the same controller and view. For some reason, while the other boolean variables work correctly, this one does not.

```
// In the controller:
bool isDatabaseRecipeRevisionSame = true;

// This evaluates to true:
isDatabaseRecipeRevisionSame = editedRecipe.Revision == savedRecipe.Revision;

Session["match"] = isDatabaseRecipeRevisionSame;


// In the view:
bool isRecipeRevisionSame = (bool)Session["match"];

// or:
bool isRecipeRevisionSame =Convert.ToBoolean(Session["match"]);
```

Regardless of whether I cast or convert the session object into the boolean in the view, the result is false. If I cast the same session object into an integer I get a zero, and using ToString() I get "False". I don't understand how some of them work as expected and this one does not. Can someone please advise?

Thanks in advance.

Edit: responses to comments.

The Recipe.Revision variables are integers. The savedRecipe is retrieved from a database, edited and stored locally as editedRecipe. Before the edits are saved back to the database, savedRecipe.Revision is retrieved from the DB again to confirm that no-one else has changed the DB version since it was first retrieved. If the revisions match, then the edits are saved to the DB.

There are no other threads changing these values, nor are there currently any users other than myself using this database. I actually replicated the problem today within a single method, so I think DBro's probably right about it being a case-sensitivity problem. I've changed some of the code to use ViewBag since I posted this question, so I might not have to rework it any further.

Thanks for the advice.

Comment: I think this can help you:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34380363/access-session-variable-in-view

Comment: What does this mean? `isDatabaseRecipeRevisionSame = editedRecipe.Revision == savedRecipe.Revision;`

Comment: @BogdanDoicin, it's taking the result of comparing the two storing that result into `isDatabaseRecipeRevisionSame`. So if edited and saved are the same value, then it holds `true` if not, it holds `false`.

Comment: Do you know for a fact that isDatabaseRecipeRevisionSame is true when assigning it to the session?  What happens if you set Session["match"] = true?  Are  you sure that there isn't another thread where the session values is being overwritten?

Comment: Something tells me that we have a case-sensitivity issue while trying to convert the session object into a bool (true vs. True).  If you store the true/false as a bit instead (1 or 0), do you get the correct value in your view?

Comment: @Dbro: I think you're right. I'll test it out, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In your view please use this `HttpContext.Current.Session` instead of `Session` as bellow:

```
// In the view:
var session = HttpContext.Current.Session["match"];
bool isRecipeRevisionSame = (bool)session;
```

Comment: I was originally using HttpContext.Current.Session in both places: I tried it with the simplified version and it made no difference. I posted the simple version here for clarity.